# htaccess - rewrite URL to make querystring nice

Tags: .htaccess

I have a site with a folder, and a htaccess file within that folder.  For the index.php file within that folder, I want to rewrite the querystring for a certain parameter, so that typing in this URL:

```
www.example.com/myfolder/myparameter
```

Behaves like this (ie makes `$_GET['parameter'] = 'myparameter'` in my code)

```
www.example.com/myfolder/index.php?parameter=myparameter
```

I have looked at many questions on StackOverflow, but have not managed to get this working.  My code so far is

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ %0 [QSA]
```

But that just isn't working at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) index\.php?parameter=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works. However, scripts, stylesheets and images are no longer working.  These are in URLs like www.example.com/myfolder/_images/image.png, www.example.com/myfolder/_scripts/script.js.  Can you help me fix those?

Comment: please use this 
RewriteRule !\.(js|gif|jpg|png|css|txt|eot|woff|ttf)$ - [L]

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (^.*/)([^/]+)$  $1index\.php?parameter=$2   [L,QSA]
```

**update**
sorry use @somasundaram's answer. Per-directory .htaccess rewrite rules lose the directory prefix:

> When using the rewrite engine in .htaccess files the per-directory prefix (which always is the same for a specific directory) is automatically removed for the RewriteRule pattern matching and automatically added after any relative (not starting with a slash or protocol name) substitution encounters the end of a rule set. See the RewriteBase directive for more information regarding what prefix will be added back to relative substitutions.

(from the [apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html))

Comment: @Will, see my update. As you have discovered, somasundaram's answer is the way to go!